# Java.util.NoSuchElementExecption compilation error whilst using a scanner?

Tags: java

I literally have no clue what is wrong here...

also the program you input 2 numbers and it creates a star box with x height and y width

```
import java.util.*;

public class NestedLoops{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int height;
        int width;

        System.out.println("Please input the Height");
            height = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please input the Width");
            width = s.nextInt();


            for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++ ){
                for ( int j = 0; j < width; j++ ){
                    System.out.print( "*" ) ;
                }
                    System.out.println( "" ) ;
            }


    }
}
```

Comment: It's important to distinguish between *exceptions* (which occur when the program is running) and *compilation errors* (which occur when you compile). It sounds like you're actually getting an exception, so your title shouldn't talk about compilation errors.

Comment: And I can't reproduce the problem, by the way - I run it from the command line, enter a height and a width, and it displays a box. Please give more details.

Comment: Ah yes, I was wondering this myself.. i ran it on command line a while ago and now i tried a quick online complier and it doesnt work on there. Thank you @JonSkeet

Comment: Well what *exactly* did you do on the command line, and what happened? Does the online compiler allow you to provide user input via System.in? Again, more details required...

Comment: I also literally have no clue what is wrong here. Because it executes fine.

Comment: I believe [this is how you get the exception](http://ideone.com/x4pvcd). You need to specify the input (_stdin_) beforo you run it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking whether you have a number in place already using [hasNextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) api as below

```
if (s.hasNextInt()) {
    height = s.nextInt();
}
if (s.hasNextInt()) {
    width = s.nextInt();
}
```